# Avoiding lazy loading in Datamapper in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading, ruby-datamapper

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Datamapper. I have written models using Datamapper, one of my model name is Student. In one view haml file I have written the following code:

```
-students = Student.all
-students.each |student|
 %tr
  %td= student.roll_no 
  %td= student.type if student.type
  %td= student.department.name
```

Here I have used newrelic -rpm for profiling my code. Here I found that in each iteration of the above block, one query of the form `select prop1, prop2,... from students where id ="some value"` is being generated. This is very undesired as it is taking time on each iteration of the block. I think it's due to lazy loading. I have spent nearly a week on that but found nothing to avoid this. If anyone have any idea regarding this please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add block you passed to each as well?

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful if you could show us the schema of the `Students` table in `app/db/schema.rb`.

I suspect your problem is not that each iteration of student takes so long because of lazy evaluation of each row in students, but that it has to load the department in each step. The `Student.all` is, since Rails 4, lazily evaluated, but it loads **the** whole set at once.

In order to solve your issue, you have to write `Student.includes(:department)` in your first line.

Comment: I think, the approach you suggested applies to Activerecord. But here I am using Datamapper, here there is no such db folder with schema.rb in app directory. If I am wrong, please rectify. I am not using Rails 4, my Rails version is 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can force DataMapper to preload data before embarking on the loop.

After loading the Collection into `students`, add a line such as:

```
prefetch = students.collect { |s| s.department }
```

You don't have to do anything with the `prefetch` object; DataMapper will load all the data and associate it with the `students` object. You should then find that you can iterate through the loop as expected without a separate query been generated for each. (I've just tested this on a project I'm working on and it succeeds.)